# Font Size changing by itself in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, fonts, alignment, size

In an Android application with FireMonkey I'm using TLabel in several places in my code. I have seen weird behavior regarding random changes in font size and text alignment. These properties are set to Design Time: TLabel has `TAlign = None`, `Autosize = False`, `TextSettings.HorzAlign = Leading`, `AutoTranslate = False` and default font. The problem is occurring at runtime.

NOTE: I've noticed this problem with the app installed on multiple smartphones with different versions of Android. I have also tried to change the font size in runtime, but it seems that the control is blocked and doesn't change the font size or the family.

How to fix or prevent this?

Comment: Do you have any stylesheet assigned?

Comment: No. The only configurations are made in design time, directly in the properties of TLabel

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Apparently there's a BUG in the compiler or whatever ...
To solve the problem I adjusted fonts and alignments in design time, as I had already done, but I added a TStyleBook to the main form. I just dropped TStyleBook and set `StyleBook = StyleBook1` property of the main form. It was not necessary to create or change any styles of any controls. After that, font sizes and styles of TLabel stopped changing for no reason.